# Get query parameters from url in laravel 8 api

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api

In the file `routes/api.php` I created route

```
Route::get('stories', function (Request $request) {
    return $request;
});
```

In the client side on react, I created a request to my api

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                "https://api.example.com/api/stories",
                {
                    params :
                        {
                            type : "realtime"
                        }
                }
            )
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                return false;
            })
    }, []);
```

In the Google chrome console you can see that the XHR is sent to `/api/stories?type=realtime`
But the result is always an empty array.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: are you also getting emptry result if you open the URL directly on your borwser ?`https://api.example.com/api/stories?type=realtime&test=bah`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

This retrieves values from the entire request payload regardless the HTTP verbs method used

```
Route::get('stories', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->all();
});
```

To ensure values are coming from the request query string

```
Route::get('stories', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->query('type');
});
```

Comment: aint `Request` object will return the `toArray` method when you return it in laravel 8? so doing this `return $request;` should be the same as `return $request->all()` ?